# Website images overlapping(Shopify)

Tags: html, css, image, shopify, liquid

I am using shopify and added a section using my own html into it. I added the picture of the lipstick, the face and the one under those that is being overlapped by one of the products from the 'featured products' section that comes built into the theme.  I was wondering how I would be able to fix this? Do I need to go in and fix something with liquid?

I have solved this issue by using a table in html instead; Ive provided my solution for future readers.

HTML

```
<div class="hover">
<center>
<table style="width: 182px; height: 159px;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 33px;">
<td style="width: 57.125px; height: 20px;">

  <figure><img  align=left valign=top width=350px type="image/jpeg" src="{{ 'lipstickpink.jpg' | asset_url}}" /></figure>
  <figure> <img align=left valign=bottom width=400px type="image/jpeg" src="{{ 'shadow.jpg' | asset_url}}" /> </figure>

  </td>
<td style="width: 900px; ">

  <figure><img align=center valign=top width=900px type="image/jpeg" src="{{ 'facehomepage.jpg' | asset_url}}" /></figure>

  </td>

  </center>

  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add padding to the photographs. Padding (e.g. of 10px) will add a 10px white space on all sides (unless you specify padding-top or padding-bottom etc.. which you can do if you prefer. ) You could also add a margin to the container. A negative margin-top will  shift the appearance of the position of the container upwards, likewise it can be applied to the photographs as well. (Positive or negative)

Hope this helps

Rachel

Comment: there may be margin and padding in the default theme, but if you add !important after the colon in your css, this should override the default settings

Comment: Note that using !important can be confusing later, when you try to override it and fail.

Comment: Yes this not was for the OP (and I will move it) but: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/